# In a multigang box, can I reduce the pigtails by using one single wire for all hots?

Tags: wiring, switch, code-compliance

I'm curious if it's to code to use one wire (with 1/4" spots that have the sheathing trimmed off, which connect to the terminals) for all my grounds and one wire for all my hot connections in a multi-gang switch box. This is an attempt to reduce the pigtails in the box.

Is there a term for this idea/technique? I thought it might be called daisy chaining, but I don't know if that term is specific to this technique. 
[image]

Below is a pic of what I was doing prior. I'm also curious if the wire nuts aren't big enough for all 4 of the wires, if I can safely use a wire to jump to another wire nut (reducing the wire nuts to only 3 wires each)?

[image]

Comment: Have you heard of push wire connectors? ->https://www.amazon.com/Wago-Wire-Connector-Clear-Conductor/dp/B000F5THV8/ref=pd_sim_60_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=RZHYSK0P1CDENGQ9BQ61

Comment: @Edwin - Yep, I've heard of them, and also using appropriate sized wire nuts. ;) Neither of these unfortunately are an option for my work situation. Although, I'd say doing the one wire method (if it has a name?) feels 'cleaner' than even using lots of wire nuts or wago wire connectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's an official term for this wiring technique, but it is certainly an acceptable method of wiring devices.